# What's the meaning of the word “Kaka” in Italian?

Tags: word-meaning

Can you please tell me what is the meaning in Italian of the word

> "KAKA" ?

Comment: There is no such word in italian, as you can check in any dictionary (for instance [here](http://www.treccani.it/)). Where did you find it?

Comment: A famous Brazilian football player is nicknamed “Kaká”; he played for Milan AC during several seasons. The word just resembles a quite vulgar Italian verb, so some puns with the player's name are possible.

Comment: It means poop in Amharic (a language spoken in Ethiopia...East Africa)

Comment: “Kaka” is not an Italian word, so it's off topic discussing it here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an Italian word as somebody pointed out in the comments.
Since the letter K in Italian does not exist, you might have been referring the whole time to *CACA'* which, in some parts of Italy, would be a rather unpolite shortening for the vulgar verb *cacare*, which means *to poop*.

Comment: The shortening is not especially vulgar, in itself, just regional Italian. :-)

Comment: I actually meant something different,  rather unpolite. Corrected.

Comment: Note that in some regions it's *cagare* instead of *cacare*.

Answer (score -1):

When I was little. my girlfriend's dad, who is from Italy, used this word often.  I still remember him using this word.  Mrs. C. was also from Italy, so I can attest to the fact that Italians do use this word.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! I suspect you might have misunderstood (maybe he was saying something more similar to *cagá/cagar/cacà/cacar*?). I *am* Italian and I've never seen the word *kakà* with the letter *k*.